# How to Make Column Group in Ag-Grid Tool Panel Collapsed by Default

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid with all columns defined in two groups and the column tool panel on. Currently when you open the tool panel, it keeps both groups expanded but I would like to by default keep one of them collapsed and the other expanded. Is this possible? I wasn't able to find a function in the ag-grid API to do this.

**EDIT**

The first example here shows the column groups in a tool panel: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-columns/

I want to make the column groups "Athlete" and "Competition" collapsed by default in the tool panel but leave "Medals" expanded.

Comment: not fully got what you are trying to achieve, could you provide an extended details pls

Comment: I updated my question, please let me know if my question makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

> Update

unfortunately, [ag-grid doesn't provide such possibilities yet.](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/12efbfd1b84281c6d4722d9125b802160a1bf589/packages/ag-grid-enterprise/src/sideBar/providedPanels/columns/panels/primaryColsPanel/toolPanelColumnGroupComp.ts#L140)

`setupExpandContract()` method is private and not available via API

Comment: Yes, only inside tool panel

Comment: Now, it does support contracting column groups by default inside the tool panel: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-columns/#section-visibility